# Using dch to increment release number without a suffix?

Tags: command-line, package-management, deb

I'm building my software into a deb package using the standard devscripts, and I would like to use `dch` to automatically increment the release number for non-source code changes (i.e. packaging changes and patches), as it is common in Linux distributions.

For example: the source release is `1.0.0` and I'm packaging the software as `1.0.0-1` (the first packaged release of version 1.0.0). Now I discovered a bug in the packaging (for example, a configuration file was not marked as such), so I want to release package version `1.0.0-2`.

Initially I though that `dch -i` is ideal for this, but apparently it increments from `1.0.0-1` to `1.0.0-1ubuntu1` :-( . I've looked hard into what other command line options I can use, but all I could find was options to use a different suffix (e.g. `--rebuild` will add `buildX`).

Mush I edit the release number manually every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To release `1.0.0-2` you need to use the `-U` option, see [`dch` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/dch.1.html):

```
   --upstream, -U
          Don't append distro-name1 to the version on a derived          
          distribution. Increment the Debian version.
```

Initial `debian/changelog`:

```
foo (1.0.0-1) trusty; urgency=medium

  * Initial release

 -- Sylvain Pineau <sylvain.pineau@canonical.com>  Thu, 16 Jul 2015 14:53:54 +0200
```

After `dch -U`:

```
foo (1.0.0-2) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium

  * 

 -- Sylvain Pineau <sylvain.pineau@canonical.com>  Thu, 16 Jul 2015 18:06:24 +0200

foo (1.0.0-1) trusty; urgency=medium

  * Initial release

 -- Sylvain Pineau <sylvain.pineau@canonical.com>  Thu, 16 Jul 2015 14:53:54 +0200
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. The naming convention really throws me off - so am I to understand that "Debian version" is what RPM calls "release version" ?

Comment: @Guss: See https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version for the full reference about the Debian version policy.

Comment: Got it. Though `-U` doesn't work well for me: sometime it does what I want and sometimes it doesn't increment the "Debian version" and just adds another line to the last changelog entry without incrementing the version. `-i` always increments. Frustrating.